# Someone just went through and downvoted my questions that are years old. Can anything be done about this?

Tags: discussion

These questions must be at least 3-4 years old but it looks like someone is trying to spite me for some reason?  Is there any course of action I can take if someone is just following all my questions just to down vote them?

[image]

Comment: The serial voting was already corrected.